# Position of mouse click relative to scene, not window

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mouseevent, skscene, nsevent

In my game I need to use the mouse to select units.

However, I am encountering problems as I do not know how to get the coordinates of the click relative to the game, not to the window.

For example, if Unit 1 is at the (0,0) point of the game, it could be at any point on the window depending on how I pan and zoom the window, but I want the mouse click to return (0,0) no matter how I move the window as long as I click on the same spot.

Right now I am using:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    eventPos = event.location(in: self)
    ...
}
```

(The rest of the code does not matter for the mouse click location).

This is all inside a GameScene, which is an SKScene. So how do I get the location relative to the GameScene of the mouse click?

Comment: `eventPos` should be in scene coordinates. Are you panning/zooming using SpriteKit's built-in camera? Also, did you try `let selectedUnit = atPoint(eventPos)` to select a unit?

Comment: I am using a camera made through code, it is an SKCamera node, but IS NOT the one you make by dragging one and placing one through the Game Scene SKS.

Comment: Panning an zooming are custom functions I made.

Comment: If you use the built-in SpriteKit camera for panning/zooming, the mouse positions will be in scene coordinates with the code you provided above. I also suspect it will simplify your app development effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need convert your point from view to scene coordinates:

```
eventPos = view!.convert(event.locationInWindow, to: view!.scene!)
```