# Run an SKSpriteNode object along a line drawn with the mouse in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, sprite-kit

If you let go of the left mouse button, my SKSpriteNode object should move along the line previously *"drawn"* with the mouse.

**My problem is that my sprite node is moving down when I release the left mouse button.**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    let object: SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rabbit")

    var actionArray = [SKAction()]

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        object.setScale(0.2)
        object.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        object.zPosition = 0
        object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "rabbit"), size: object.size)

        object.physicsBody?.mass = 0
        object.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
        object.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        object.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

        addChild(object)
    }

    override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {

        actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to: event.location(in: self), duration: 1))
    }

    override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {

        object.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))

        // Remove all actions from 'actionArray'.
        actionArray.removeAll()
    }
}
```

I have already tried it as shown below. **Now my sprite node moves to the first point, where I pressed down the left mouse button**.

```
override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {

    let removeAllFromActionArray = SKAction.run {

        self.actionArray.removeAll()
    }

    actionArray.append(removeAllFromActionArray)
    object.run(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
}
```

I've already tried `view! .Convert (event.locationInWindow, to: view! .Scene!)` Instead of `event.location (in: self)`, as indicated in *[Position of mouse click relative to scene, not window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911319/position-of-mouse-click-relative-to-scene-not-window)*, but the result was the same.

I suspect that the bug lies in `override func mouseUp(with event: event)`.
**Where does the error lie or is there another solution?**

Comment: Not a macOS developer, but the docs say that you use `event.location(in:SKNode)` on a descendant of scene, meaning there may be an issue with scene itself.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the duplicate doesn't seem to apply for the OP and raised the issue on Meta as well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389820/578411 can you revisit this and re-evaluate your close vote?

Comment: @rene  I flagged it for reopen.  OP  your coordinates are not lining up correctly,  Add a new sprite node when you are dragging to draw a line and determine what you are doing wrong. 
 `override func mouseDragged(with event: NSEvent) {
        let pos = event.location(in: self)
        actionArray.append(SKAction.move(to:pos , duration: 1))
        let spr = SKSpriteNode(color:.blue,size:CGSize(width:1,height:1)
        spr.position = pos
        addChild(spr)
    }
`

Comment: @PetterFriberg It isn't an answer though, just a diagnostic tool.